# How to check page contains str using XmlHttpRequest without loading whole file?

Tags: javascript, stream, xmlhttprequest

I want check is file (get by XmlHttpRequest) contains given string.
I don't want to load whole file because its huge.
How to stop loading file on any occurrence of given string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use XHR streaming. An example would be:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', '/stream');
xhr.seenBytes = 0;

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { // 1
  if(xhr.readyState > 2) {
    var newData = xhr.responseText.substr(xhr.seenBytes); // 2
    // process newData

    xhr.seenBytes = xhr.responseText.length; // 3
  }
};
```

1. Subscribe to state and progress notifications
2. Extract new data from partial response
3. Update processed byte offset